# Typescript: Class return number instead of object instance

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Hi guys Im working with Typescript, Nest Js and TypeORm

Im trying to make class validator for parameters:

```
import { IsNumber, IsPositive } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class validateID {
    @Transform((id) => parseInt(id, 10))
    @IsNumber()
    @IsPositive()
    id: number;
}
```

But when I specify it in my Route controller I says that I should return typeOf validateID but I would like to return number since the number is validated and should be returned

```
  @Get(':id')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    async getUser(@Param('id') id: validateID): Promise<CrudResponse<User>> {
        data: await this.userService.getUser(id), // here it asks for type to be validateID, but I would like it to be number

    }
```

Comment: Is the [ValidationPipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe) anywhere previously registered?

Comment: Yes globally in boostrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to return number in my route like this:

```
validateID['id']
```

So the code in route would look like this:

```
@Get(':id')
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    async getUser(@Param('id') id: validateID['id']): Promise<CrudResponse<User>> {
        data: await this.userService.getUser(id), // here it asks for type to be validateID, but I would like it to be number

    }
```